# How do I avoid having my gun stolen in Zombies "Five" map, around level 5 or 6?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

In the Zombies map "Five" (in the Pentagon) a guy spawns sometimes that will run up and pull the gun out of your hand. I think this happens around level 5 or 6. How do you defend against this guy? I haven't been able to kill him yet- is there a good way to avoid having your gun theifed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This doctor thief appears in every 6-8 rounds, normally you should hear a low-note scream and the room will get slightly darker. If you are playing with your friends, not all of them may see him (but appears to see number bloods when he runs around) but they can still kill him. To avoid him you must run away from him and shoot him when you're from afar.

Repeat this method:

1. Run away until you're slightly far from the thief.
2. Look back and shoot at the thief.
3. Continue running away when he gets close.
4. Repeat.

When you have successfully killed him, your weapons are returned, including a drop of ammo. Sometimes you may have a drop that reduces the price of upgrading your weapon for a limit of time (a `$` sign will appear at the bottom if this is active) from `5000` to `2500` points, also random-weapon box will be set `10` points for every time you open the box. But the points are lowered over a short period of time.

The best method to kill him is to use a machine gun or a light machine gun with a large magazine, shoot every bullet in him, it takes quite some time to take him down due to his large amount of health points but when playing with team mates, you are more likely to take him down quickly. A good way to kill him is to use the upgraded Colt M1911, Mustang and Sally.

---

The Kino der Toten map does not have a thief doctor but the Kino der Toten map has Zombie dogs/wolves (at least 10+) that run and attack towards you and your team mates which is more annoying than the doctor thief.

Comment: What do you mean by "but appears to see number bloods when he runs around"?

Comment: @leecbaker: He means it looks like a red cloud, but when you got near it you will notice that it is a cloud of numbers with red-font.

Comment: Exactly my point. :)

Answer (score 1):

"or somewhere" is actually Pentagon :)

And the guy who steals guns is the Crazy Doctor (aka the Pentagon Thief).
Defending against this tough guy is not a viable option.

If you are less than three players, do what normal people do: run.

Don't even think about close combat, he has lots of HP.

This semi-boss opponent is one of the few baddies in the whole game, whom you will need all your team mates to bring down.

Comment: could I please have some comment on the -1 at least? Is there any wrong information in here?

Answer (score 0):

The thief-round is a round where there are no regular zombies but a zombie-wearing-lab-coat will appear that steals your equipped weapon and teleport you to the laboratory. This will start to occur when you turn-on the power and happens only at 6th-8th rounds. He(Doctor-thief) will be visible only to the targeted/locked player and those who's weapons are already stolen on that round, the other player will just see a red-cloud but when you get near you will notice that it is a cloud of numbers with red-font when you get close(don't be afraid if it is just a cloud, it won't steal your weapon until your turn). It is easy to distinguish this round through having a dark-blue tint color of the surroundings and a voice of the female announcer will be heard at start of the round.

Here are the rewards/drop for this round round type:
 - Max Ammo only: If you were unable to kill it
 - Fire-sale + Max Ammo + Return Weapons: If you were able to kill it with atleast one player of the player's weapon was stolen
 - Bonfire Sale + Max Ammo: If you were able to kill it without any of the player's weapon got stolen

**The strategy:**
At first rounds, it is hard to get a Fire-sale 'coz you only have regular weapons. Just let it steal your not-favorite weapon or gun that you can get easily. But on next thief-round someone from your team must already have the winter howl/fury(one player was able to have this at a time) and atleast one player(not the winter howl/fury carrier) have a ray-gun.

It is more effective on the strategy room upstairs with railings(dunno what it was called). The target need to run-around and don't get near to the thief(just kite it) while the other player's shouldn't get on the target's way.

The Winter Howl/Fury carrier should conserve the ammo of this weapon before the thief round. He/she should fire it regularly on the thief-doctor(twice every turn at first but once every turn when it looks slow) to slow it down. If the Winter Howl/Fury carrier is the target, just fire it and run-away or just follow it if you're not.

The Ray-gun carrier should unload all of the ray-gun's ammo to the thief and it will be down in no-time. The other player's don't have the wonder weapons or not the target would might fire their gun on the thief but those weapons might not be effective.

The thief is as fast as a sprinting player but it is always sprinting when it got its top speed(it start walking but have high acceleration).

Answer (score 0):

It's tough not letting the Pentagon Theif take your weapon. Get away from him as far as you can and shoot him quickly. (Double Tap and Slight of Hand might help) If you teleport, he might be behind you or not. Either way, be careful. If you killed him without having your weapon stolen, you will get "Max Ammo" and "Bonfire Sale." If he did get your weapon and you did kill him you will get your weapon back and get "Max Ammo" and "Fire Sale." If he gets away you will not get your weapon back and you will only get "Max Ammo." If you have no ammo left to kill him... good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with `BurningtheCodeigniter` answer, but I only want to add:

If you play alone the easiest way to kill him is:

- Do **NOT** buy a weapon that will replace your standard pistol(you may buy a weapon, but make sure that you still have your pistol, you **WILL** need it)
- Get yourself a `Quick revive`
- Turn on the power
- When `Pentagon Thief` appears and you see him, kill yourself(use grenades and make sure that he's close enough, but not too close :D )
- While you are down(assuming you still have `Quick revive`), your standard pistol(`M1911`) will turn into `Mustang and Sally`, a dual-wielded `M1911` that has 1000 damage + 1200 splash(standard one has only 20 damage).
- So now you are: down, waiting for revive, you see `Pentagon Thief` and you have `Mustang and Sally`. I think there is no need to explain what to do now :)

You can now easily kill him. Enjoy your `Hands Off the Merchandise` trophy :)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually very easy to avoid the doctor on the first meeting. Save up to 5000 points before the power is on, upgrade the first pistol, then when he attacks you, just make sure you are on the walkway on the same floor as double tap. Once you see him, unload on him while running and he dies relatively quick. Works every time, better when he attacks you first so you can get Bonfire Sale